# First hitting time expectation and Markov property

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, markov-chains, expectation

Let $H_A$ be the first hitting time, such that $H_A\geqslant1$, so we have $X_0=i\notin A$. 
All texts I looked at, state without any further justification that
$$
\mathbb E(H_A\mid X_1=j, X_0=i)=1+\mathbb E(H_A\mid X_0=j).
$$
follows from the Markov property.

It makes intuitive sense yet how does one derive it?

Comment: personally, i do not see anything to derive. If you really want, you can look up shift operators and how to define markov processes on a family of probability measures indexed by the state space. Personally, i dislike the notation you currently use. I prefer the notation $E_i$ to mean a family of probability measures supporting the markov chain such that $P_i(X_0=i)=1$. if you adopt that notation, shift operator is how you would do it, but the proof would not be instructive, as it is just your 'intuitive sense'

Comment: @Lost1: But intro texts routinely prove even more intuitive things in a very thorough manner. If it follows from the Markov property, I expect us being able to start with the LHS, then use $\mathbb P (X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|X_n=i_n,\ldots,X_0=i_0)=\mathbb P (X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|X_n=i_n)$ somewhere in the middle, and later end up with the RHS.

Comment: you can drop the $X_0=i$ on the LHS, then you can arrive at the RHS straightaway... technically, the $H_A$ on the left is not the same $H_A$ on the right, but they have the same distribution, if you see what I mean.

Comment: @LeoSchmidt You want a stronger statement of the Markov property:  $\mathbb{E}(f(X_1,X_2,\dots)\mid X_1=j,X_0=i)=\mathbb{E}(f(X_1,X_2,\dots)\mid X_1=j)$ for any bounded, measurable function $f$ of (possibly) infinitely many variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $$H_A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \prod_{k=0}^n 1_{(X_k\notin A)}=1_{(X_0\notin A)}\left[1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n1_{(X_k\notin A)}\right]=1_{(X_0\notin A)}[1+H_A^\prime],$$ 
where $H_A=f(X_0,X_1,X_2,\dots)$ and $H_A^\prime=f(X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots)$.
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}(H_A\mid X_1=j,X_0=i)
&=&1+\mathbb{E}\left(H_A^\prime \mid X_1=j,X_0=i\right)\\[5pt]
&=&1+\mathbb{E}\left(H_A^\prime  \mid X_1=j\right) \\[5pt]
&=&1+\mathbb{E}\left(H_A  \mid X_0=j\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Try to find the places in this argument where we use $i\notin A$, the Markov property, 
and the time homogeneity of the chain.